# Validate against NaN values for <input type="number">

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, nan, angular-custom-validators

I am creating a form using Angular Reactive forms, and for UX reasons I am trying to disable the form's submit when certain invalid values are inserted in an `<input type="number">` field, for example negative numbers or non-integer numbers.

The problem is that when I insert a value that even if allowed by `<input type="number">` would usually evaluate to `NaN`, like, for example, the letter `e` alone, the minus or plus sign without a number following it, or even a number too big to be represented by a TypeScript `number`, instead evaluates to `null` when accessing the value via `control.value` or `control.getRawValue()`.

EDIT: The form also needs to be submittable when the input field is empty. This is sadly a non-negotiable requirement, and I also cannot use a default value like `0` for the field.

This is a minimum reproducible example for what I tried (it only tries to block NaN values).

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormBuilder, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="print()">
      <input type="number" name="control" id="control" formControlName="control" >
      <button type="submit" [disabled] ="formGroup.invalid">print</button>
    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ReactiveFormNumberControl';

  formGroup

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = this._fb.group({
      control: this._fb.control<number | null>(null, {
        validators: [noNaNValidator]
      })
    })
  }

  print = () => {
    console.log(this.formGroup.value)
  }
}

const noNaNValidator: ValidatorFn = (
  control: AbstractControl<number | null>,
) => {
  const value = control.value

  if (Number.isNaN(value)) {
    // Value is null and not NaN, so this is never reached because Number.isNaN(null) is false,
    // the control (and group) is marked valid and the submit button is not disabled
    return {
      invalidValue: {
        value: value
      },
    }
  }
  return null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking at Angular issues related to this on GitHub, more precisely [Issue #2962](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2962), I found a workaround for this, leveraging HTML5's `badInput` property present present in some types of `<input>` elements, `number` included.

I've wrote a custom validator directive, similar to the one shown [in this comment on Angular Issue #2962](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2962#issuecomment-1268879968), but unlike that one the directive I've wrote has to be explicitly applied, and for now can only be applied to `<input type="number">` fields (but this should be easy to change if needed, by changing the directive's `selector`).

**bad-input-validator.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, ValidationErrors, Validator } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type=number][appBadInputValidator]',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: BadInputValidatorDirective,
    multi: true,
  }]
})
export class BadInputValidatorDirective implements Validator {

  private onChangeCallback?: () => void;

  constructor(private _element: ElementRef) { }

  validate(_: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const inputElement = this._element.nativeElement
    return inputElement.validity.badInput ? { 'badInput': true } : null
  }

  registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn
  }
}
```

This can probably be improved somehow, but for now it does what I need to. When  I apply the `appBadInputValidator` to an `<input type="number">` element, and I input a value that would parse to `NaN`, the `FormControl` and `FormGroup` get marked as invalid and the submit button is correctly disabled.

This directive works similar Angular.JS's form validation, that kept track of `badInput`, but this behavior is currently not present in Angular, at least as of version 16.2.6.

Big thanks to amc1804 on GitHub for posting a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [NumberValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/NumberValueAccessor) is responsible to convert every invalid value to `null`.

This is the expected behavior.

Comment: Looking at the documentation and source code of NumberValueAccessor that makes sense. Could writing a custom value accessor directive that extends NumberValueAccessor be a solution for my particular use case? Or would that just open a whole new can of worms?

Comment: `NumberValueAccessor` is declared in the `FormsModule` I'm not sure this would work to have 2 directives matching the same input  !

Comment: In that case I might open a feature request to the Angular team on GitHub to see if conditionally allowing NaN/invalid values is something that could make sense for other users. Thank you for the explaination.

Comment: While looking at Angular issues on GitHub I found a workaround for this. See my own answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a value is `NaN`, you should first convert the value to a number if it's possible and then use method `Number.isNaN()`, in your example you can try:

```
  const value: any = control.value;
  const parsedValue = parseFloat(value);

  if (Number.isNaN(parsedValue)) {
    // Value is null and not NaN, so this is never reached because Number.isNaN(null) is false,
    // the control (and group) is marked valid and the submit button is not disabled
    return {
      invalidValue: {
        value: value
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: While this indeed makes the form invalid when I try to type a NaN value, it also has the undesired side effect of making the form invalid when the field is empty. This was not specified in the original question (which I will update), so that's on me.

Comment: btw you can simplify add second condition next to `Number.isNaN(parsedValue)` something like this `parsedValue && Number.isNaN(parsedValue)`, it will be checked only when some value exist in field

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested, but if I try an invalid input, like `e` or `-`, the submit button is still enabled, like in my initial example.